# Undefined offset when creating/adding Multi-Dimensional array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, error-handling

I am adding to an array on the fly, using code similar to this;

```
 $arrayF[$f+1][$y][$x+1] = $value+1;
```

But I receive this in the error report:

Undefined offset: 1

QUESTION: Why do I get an undefined offset when I am trying to CREATE an array value?

What can I do about it?

Further info, if relevant:
It occurs in a loop as so, where I am 'sprawling' through a masterArray

```
if (is_array($arrayF[$f])){ 
    foreach ($arrayF[$f] as  $key2 => $arrayF2) {
        $y = $key2;
        foreach ($arrayF2 as $key3 =>$value) {
            $x = $key3;
            if (($y<=100)&& ($y>=1)&&($x<=100)&&($x>=1)){
                if ($value < $arrayMaster[$y][$x])  {
                    $arrayMaster[$y][$x] = $value;//resets value in a master array
                    $arrayF[$f+1][$y][$x+1] = $value+1;//creates a new array for F to 'sprawl' with
                    $max = $f+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried specify that is an array with $arrayF = new array()? it can help maybe

Comment: @Marco, no it hasn-t been set, could definitely try. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoMura: arrays don't require the `new` keyword. They never have, and never will and for this code to even get in the loop `$arrayF` _has_ to be an array, or the outer `if` would evaluate to `false`, so initializing `$arrayF` won't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, because when you do this: `$arrayF[$f+1][$y][$x+1] = $value+1;`, you can't be sure that `$arrayF[$f+1]` is a valid offset/index/key. All you know for sure is that `is_array($arrayF[$f])` is true.

The fix is rather simple:

```
if (!isset($arrayF[$f+1]) || !is_array($arrayF[$f+1])) {
    $arrayF[$f+1] = array(
        $y => array()
    );
} else if (!is_array($arrayF[$f+1][$y])) {
        $arrayF[$f+1][$y] = array();
}
$arrayF[$f+1][$y][$x+1] = $value+1;
```

Now why are you getting the notice? That's because, if `$arrayF[$f+1]` doesn't exist, PHP will happily create it for you when you do a simple assignment like `$arrayF[$f+1] = 'foobar';`. However, you're accessing a (possibly) non-existent offset (which would evaluate to `null`), and try to use it as an array: `$arrayF[$f+1][$y]`, if `$arrayF[$f+1]` doesn't exist, there can't be a `$y` index in there, hence the notice: PHP is warning you about a possible bug in your code

*Update:*
As discussed in the comments below: `is_array` can produce an undefined offset notice, seeing as it assumes that the argument you pass to it actually exists. To avoid such notices from being produced, an `isset` check is required, so I've updated the code above accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, So I would have to prepopulate ALL values of a multi-dimensional arrays until level dimensions-1?

Comment: @Gamemorize: Then leave out the `if`, and just write `$arrayF[$f+1] = array($y => array($x+1 => $value+1));`, but be weary: in that case, you're bound to re-assign `$arrayF[$f+1]` endlessly, effectively making your loops redundant

Comment: Thx Elias, I'll have a go at your first suggestions, which effectively dynamically declares then assigns. Should be back 'shortly' to accept answer. Thx again!

Comment: think of `$array[$i]` as saying _"give me value `$i` in variable `$array`, and do something with it"_, if you want `$array[$i][$j]`, then think of it as `($array[$i])[$j]` (take the value of `$array[$i]`, then give me index `$j` of that value). So in order to add a value 3 levels deep, you have to make sure that all the arrays exist: the main variable must be an array (`$arrayF`), the offset you use must resolve to an array (`$f+1`) and the offset in there (`$y`) must be an array, too. Only then can you assign safely (create `$x+1`, and assign a value). Hence the checks are required

Comment: It seems to be that is_array($array[$x]) will throw undefined offset but isset($array[$x]) does not. Is this the case as expected?

Comment: @Gamemorize: Yes, it is. `isset` will check if a variable _or_ index exists, regardless. `is_array` will evaluate the expression you're passing to see if it's an array. It simply assumes the variable/array index exists

Comment: Fine, best change the answer and if you could mention the problem in using is_array to throw errors, I can accept the answer. thanks again!