# Getting error of JSON Parser in my code

Tags: php, android, json

I am creating a registration form and sending data to MySql database through json in android but whenever i do click on submit button I got the following error in my logcat.

```
    12-19 18:19:22.145: E/JSON Parser(2620): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-19 18:19:22.365: W/dalvikvm(2620): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at app.restaurant.Register_Activity$RegisterUser.doInBackground(Register_Activity.java:162)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at app.restaurant.Register_Activity$RegisterUser.doInBackground(Register_Activity.java:1)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-19 18:19:22.865: E/AndroidRuntime(2620):     ... 5 more
```

**This is my android code of registering form**

**Register_Activity.java**

```
public class Register_Activity extends Activity {



//RadioGroup rg;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  // RadioButton rb;
 //  int id;

TextView nm,ad,ps,ph,em;
 String password;
    Button bnt_Submit;
    EditText edt_email,edt_password,edt_name,edt_phone,edt_address,edt_lastName;
    JSONObject json;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.9/adminfoodOld/public/jsonregister";

    //http://www.truzzinfotech.co.nz/admin/public/jsonregister


    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";



    //JSONArray phn,eml,pas,add,nam;
    String gender ="Male";
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

/*
     nm  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXt_Name);
     em  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXt_Email);
     ph  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXt_Ph);
     ps  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXt_password);
     ad  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXt_Ad);

    */
    // rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    bnt_Submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
    edt_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_Email);
    edt_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_Password);
    edt_name  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_Name);
    edt_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_Phone);
    edt_address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_Address);
    edt_lastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edt_LastName);

/*   id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
      rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(id);*/
    bnt_Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            password = edt_password.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidPassword(password)) {
                edt_password.setError("The Passward must be at least 8 character ");
            }




              // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), gender+"Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new RegisterUser().execute();



            }

    });

}


private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 7) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  gender= rb.getText().toString();

         String firstname =edt_name.getText().toString();
         String emails =edt_email.getText().toString();
         String phone =edt_phone.getText().toString();
         String address =edt_address.getText().toString();
         String lastname =edt_lastName.getText().toString();






     List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", firstname));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emails));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",address));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gender));
     params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lastname));
     Log.d("param",params1.toString());

 json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params1);


     Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    /* Log.d("Gender", gender.toString());
     Log.d("name", firstname.toString());
     Log.d("pass", password.toString());
     Log.d("email", emails.toString());
     Log.d("lastname", lastname.toString());
     Log.d("address", address.toString());*/



     try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
            /*  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);*/


            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ravi kujaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // closing this screen
                //finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product



            }
     }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
    return null;





    }




    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();


                    /* try {


                            JSONObject json1 = json.getJSONObject("detail");




                    //   phn,eml,pas,add,nam;

                     phn = json1.optJSONArray("phone");
                     eml = json1.optJSONArray("email");
                     pas = json1.optJSONArray("password");
                     add = json1.optJSONArray("address");
                     nam = json1.optJSONArray("name");

                //  Log.d("Else_Part", json.toString());

                    Log.d("Name", nam.getString(0));
                    Log.d("Phone", phn.getString(0));
                    Log.d("Email", eml.getString(0));
                    Log.d("Password", pas.getString(0));
                    Log.d("Address", add.getString(0));


                    //edt_email,edt_password,edt_name,edt_phone,edt_address;
                    if(nam != null) {
                        nm.setText(nam.getString(0));
                        }

                        if(eml!= null ){
                        em.setText(eml.getString(0));
                        }
                        if(phn!= null ){
                        ph.setText(phn.getString(0));
                        }
                        if(pas!= null ){
                        ps.setText(pas.getString(0));
                        }
                        if(add!= null ){
                        ad.setText(add.getString(0));
                        }





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                */



        }




    }

}
```

This is my php code result encoded in json

```
{"detail":{"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."],"firstname":["The firstname field is required."],"lastname":["The lastname field is required."],"phone":["The phone field is required."],"address":["The address field is required."]},"success":0}
```

**This is my Php file**

```
<?php

class FrontUserController extends \BaseController {

    /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{

    if(controllerAssignView('frontuser'))      
    {

    $frontuser = frontuser::all();

    return View::make('admin.registered')->with('data', $frontuser);
    }
    else
    {
            return Redirect::to('index');
    }
}


    public function jsonregister()
{

        $inputs = Input::all();
        $validator = Validator::make(
            array(
                'email' => $inputs['email'],
                'password' => $inputs['password'],
                'firstname' => $inputs['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $inputs['lastname'],
                'phone' => $inputs['phone'],
                'address' => $inputs['address']

            ),
            array(
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:frontuser',
                'password' => 'required|min:8',
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'lastname' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required|numeric',
                'address' => 'required'

            )
        );
    if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            $userDetail = array();
            $userDetail['detail'] = $messages;
            $userDetail['success'] = 0;
            return $userDetail;
        }
        else
        {

                $Frontuser = new frontuser;
                $Frontuser->email = $inputs['email'];
                $Frontuser->password =  Hash::make($inputs['password']);
                $Frontuser->firstname = $inputs['firstname'];
                $Frontuser->lastname = $inputs['lastname'];
                $Frontuser->phone = $inputs['phone'];
                $Frontuser->address = $inputs['address'];
                $Frontuser->status = $inputs['active'];
                $Frontuser->gender = $inputs['gender'];
                if($inputs['type'] != 'null'){$Frontuser->$inputs['type'] =1;}

                $Frontuser->save();

                $user = frontuser::where('email', '=', $inputs['email'])->take(1)->get();


                    $userDetail = array();
                    $userDetail['detail']['firstname'] = $user[0]->firstname;
                    $userDetail['detail']['lastname'] = $user[0]->lastname;
                    $userDetail['detail']['gender'] = $user[0]->gender;
                    $userDetail['detail']['phone'] = $user[0]->phone;
                    $userDetail['detail']['address'] = $user[0]->address;
                    if($user[0]->facebook == 1){$userDetail['detail']['login'] = 'registered with facebook.';}
                    if($user[0]->twitter == 1){$userDetail['detail']['login'] = 'registered with twitter.';}
                    if($user[0]->googleplus == 1){$userDetail['detail']['login'] = 'registered with googleplus.';}
                    $userDetail['success'] = 1;
                    return $userDetail;

        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: your getting the nullpointer exception,so please  show line  `Register_Activity.java:162` line

Comment: Look at the error message more closely: _"<!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot..."_. PHP isn't returning a JSON string like the one you posted here, it's returning a markup page, starting with a `<!DOCTYPE>` and so on, which is of course invalid JSON

Comment: This is in line no. 162

 Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

Comment: So you mean there is error in PHP code

Comment: @typing....: possibly, not necessarily. If PHP throws an exception, or produces a notice, then that will result in invalid JSON, of course, but it's very likely that you're not setting the correct headers in your response (cf my answer)

Comment: i just updated my php code in my question can you please check it is it correct or not

Comment: Have you tested your URL with REST Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important**:

The answer below deals with how to ensure the correct headers are sent, but this can only work if your code itself doesn't contain any errors. Your code, however, does have some issues that need to be addressed ASAP:

```
$userDetail = array();
$userDetail['detail']['firstname'] = $user[0]->firstname;
```

This statement ***will*** produce a notice (undefined offset), because `$userDetail` is initialized to an empty array (1D), and then used as a 2D associative array. If php.ini is set to `E_STRICT | E_ALL` this will (rightfully) generate a notice. Fix it:

```
$userDetail = array('detail' => array());
```

If you're unsure as to why your code produces this notice [I've explained this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27544930/1230836)

---

The PHP script you're calling isn't generating a pure JSON string. The exception message tells you the string's value starts with a `<!DOCTYPE`. You'll need to set the appropriate headers in PHP by adding this to your script (at the very top, no output can be sent prior to this point):

```
<?php //before this opening tag, not even a space is allowed!
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = ['get' => 'data', 'here'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Of course, if the PHP script contains errors (notices, uncaught exceptions etc...), then the output will be messed up because of that. Debug the script thoroughly, and perhaps check what the response looks like in Java by printing (or writing) `json.toString()` to a log or tmp file

*Update:*

It looks like you're using a PHP framework (Laravel most likely). Check that framework's docs to see if it doesn't have a response component that handles JSON responses for you. In case you're using Laravel, the action should return like so:

```
return Response::json($userDetail);
```

cf [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses)

Comment: i just updated my php code in my question can you please check it is it correct or not

Comment: this is the correct answer to the general problem. @typing.... it seems you are using a PHP framework. you could check if the framework provides a function to return only json data. Otherwise there is the possibility that the framework wraps the result in a HTML frame

Comment: @typing....: Updated my answer, because your code contains errors that need fixing before you can get this to work (undefined offset notices will send the headers)

Comment: i am using laravel mvc. Sorry for the late reply